# Change what directory Babel plugins are resolved against?

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs

I'm getting this error:

> Unknown plugin "transform-class-properties" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/me/Projects/myproj/src"

The message is pretty clear, so I know *why* it's happening, but I want to change where Babel looks for the plugins/presets/packages.

I'm using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) with [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) via [rollup-plugin-babel](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel).

The options I'm giving it are:

```
{ plugins: [ 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-object-rest-spread' ],
  babelrc: false }
```

However, I can't find [an option](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel#usage) [to change](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/#options) where Babel looks for the plugins. Is there no way to do this **without** rewriting my plugins list to use absolute paths?

---

I also can't find a public API method for extracting the dependencies from `.babelrc`, so it's pretty hard to manually rewrite the file to use full paths. N.B. Babel configs might also be stored in package.json, and there's been some talk about adding support for .babelrc.js too -- I really don't want to maintain my own project that searches for all the different places a babel config might be hiding, parse the file(s), and scan it for all the plugins, with and without the arbitrary `babel-plugin-` prefixes.

Comment: So you ran `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and your node_modules shows `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` ?

Comment: @bhantol I don't understand what you're getting at. If I run that command, sure, it'll create a directory under `node_modules`. My problem exists because I'm trying to separate the babel configuration (one project) from the application code (a separate project).

Comment: You can customize it in `plugins:[]` in babelrc as per  `https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpreset-paths` but I don;t understand why you want separate locations for the plugins. You could use this as a dependency of your configuration project and have your configuration project added as a dependency to your application project.

Comment: BTW the link I provided also allows paths.

Comment: @bhantol I specifically wrote in the question that I **do not want to rewrite the plugin paths**. The goal is that the application should not have to care about the 800 different babel plugins that are in effect. The config project should take care of finding/resolving everything. I need more control over where Babel searches :\

Comment: I had to do exactly what you did but in my case the `config` project (which I called `commons-rollup-builder`) was an external dependency but I left individual project to have their .babelrc but I could easily inline the babel config in my rollup.config and babelrc as false without any issues of plugins. If this sounds like addressing your problem I could post the solution pasting snippets from my project. But that solution will involve not customizing the plugins path.

Comment: @bhantol Wait..how did you do that? Now that I think about it, the problem could just be current working directory. The script is ran in the context of the app, so if the Babel plugins are resolved against CWD it won't find them...but if I just change the CWD to the config project dir...would it work? Or did you do something different?

Comment: Gist: The default plugins dir `node_modules` that babel will search for. So if your `commons-rollup-builder` is a `devDependency` to each of your 800 projects and `commons-rollup-builder` has `dependency` to all the common `babel-plugin-xxxxxx` when each of these projects are built they will essentially have all the required plugins. Now you could have your babel config in a rollup.config.js which is inside that  `commons-rollup-builder` project. All the 800 projects have to simply refer to `node_modules/commons-rollup-builder/rollup.config.js` to build.

Comment: This achieves sharing of rollup config as well as sharing of babel configs and those dependencies will be transitively installed as a result of `commons-rollup-builder`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NODE_PATH to do the same.

```
$ npx babel test.js
Unknown plugin "external-helpers" specified in "/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/babeltest/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/babeltest"
```

After specifying the path for modules in a different location

```
$ NODE_PATH=/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/babeltest2/node_modules npx babel test.js
function test() {
   this.abc = function (url) {
      return console.log(url);
   };
}
```

`NODE_PATH` environment variable allows you to specify additional locations where the modules can be searched for

Comment: How are you rubbing the script?

Comment: Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/390b8f9201e767bf7fda18c93f01edff#file-bundilio-js-L79). As you can see, I'm trying to parse the `.babelrc`, recursively looping through it, looking for anything that says "plugins", and then resolving the package against my config project, rather than the app project, and rewriting the options. This is obviously super brittle because if Babel changes the config at all, or adds support for `.babelrc.js` or whatever, then my tool breaks. I'd *much* rather call into some Babel API to pull out the list of plugins, or at least just set the dir.

Comment: There are two was you can do, either you can set `NODE_PATH` in script using `process.env.NODE_PATH = "xyz"` or you can in your case set the path, require the modules listed in plugin, get the absolute path from the module loaded and change the plugin path to the actual full path